# Ajax-обновление количества избранных товаров

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Использую плагин YITH WOOCOMMERCE WISHLIST на своем сайте для реализации избранных товаров. Пытаюсь заставить обновляться без перезагрузки количество товаров в шапке сайта, которые находятся в избранном.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто-то сможет подсказать что можно сделать с этим кодом, чтобы количество начало обновляться моментально без перезагрузки страницы.

```
<div class="header_account_list header_wishlist">
  <a href="<?php echo esc_url(YITH_WCWL()->get_wishlist_url()); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr__('Избранное', 'lafka') ?>">
     <span class="lnr lnr-heart"></span>
     <span class="item_count"><?php echo esc_html(YITH_WCWL()->count_products()); ?></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Пробовали? https://support.yithemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001372967-Wishlist-How-to-count-number-of-products-wishlist-in-ajax

Answer (score 0):

не знаю на сколько это актуально, но возможно кому то пригодится

в functions.php нужно добавить этот код

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_yith_wishlist_count', 'get_wishlist_count' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_update_yith_wishlist_count', 'get_wishlist_count' );

function get_wishlist_count() {
    wp_send_json( [ 'count' => function_exists( 'yith_wcwl_count_all_products' ) ? yith_wcwl_count_all_products() : 0 ] );
}
```

в файл js

```
let updateWishlistCount = {
    init() {
        this.events();
    },
    events() {
        jQuery( document ).on( 'added_to_wishlist removed_from_wishlist', this.getWishlistCount.bind( this ) )
        },
    getWishlistCount() {
        jQuery.ajax( {
            url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',  // url лучше брать из json c настройками темы
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'update_yith_wishlist_count'
            }
        } ).success( function( response ) {
             // нужно заменить селектор на ваш
             jQuery( '.wishlist-count' ).text( response.count );
        } );
    }
};
updateWishlistCount.init();
```